# Cannot Verify iCoud Account

Tags: email, icloud, verification

Steps:

1. Logged in to iCloud with a valid email address after installing Yosemite.
2. Sent the verification email.
3. Tapped on the "verify" link in the email.
4. Email account verified says the web page

However, System Preferences > iCloud still says "Account Not Verified".  I tried re-sending the email but a second one never gets sent.

I also tapped on the link for the first email a second time and it says "Account already verified".

I also rebooted.

Also note that I just upgraded from Mountain Lion to Yosemite.  However, this is the first time I added iCloud.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does your login work within your Browser?

Comment: Good suggestion! I tried this and when I try to login I get a CSS popup which says "Account Not Verified" and "Check your email at <email> for instructions on how to verify your account". However, I received an email to "chris@example.com" when I expected to receive it at "admin@example.com" saying someone logged into my iCloud account. Strange, so I tapped the link to manage the account, and lo and behold my apple ID is "admin" but the email address was "chris".

Comment: There was an option to make my email the same as my apple ID which I exercised.  An immediate verification occurred and I am now able to log into iCloud.  I set these email addresses up years ago and so for whatever reason I set the email address different from the apple ID.  Anyway, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Please see comments in the post above for the solution.  Basically, my email address was different from my Apple ID.